# Move image to right side in displayType Summery in Orchard cms

Tags: orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. I have a `content type` name animal. It has some `text fields` and a `MediaLibraryPicker field`. In the `displayType Summery`, I want to show `MediaLibraryPicker field` on the right side.

My problem is that I can't find relevant template to define classes for css. How can i Achieve this ?

Comment: 'On the right side', you can just add it to Placement.info: `<Match ContentType="Animal"><Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="/AsideSecond:1" /></Match>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `shape alternate` for this specific case and render the html according to your needs. Please have a look at the docs:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Alternates/

Also, you can easily identify the shape alternate names by activating the `Shape Tracing` module:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools/